# External javascript for collapsible menu not running on website

Tags: javascript, html

So basically, I've got some javascript that I (literally) ripped directly from w3.
It's meant to be a clickable menu that opens up and displays check boxes, however, it's not actually opening when I load the webpage. It works perfectly fine within their own editor, and oxygen isn't spitting any errors out at me, so I'm at a bit of a loss.
Below is a snippet of my HTML.

```
<body>
    <h1>Title</h1>
        <button type="button" class="collapsible">Content Header</button>
        <div class="content">
            <label class="container">Content<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
                <span class="checkmark"></span><br />
            </label>
        </div>
</body>
```

and here's the javascript for the collapsible menu (that isn't working)

```
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.display === "block") {
      content.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      content.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Did you add the `<script>` tag that links your external js file? If yes then either place it at the bottom or just add `defer` to it. Also, try adding some `console.log()`s to see if the file is actually linked properly and see if anything is getting stored in `coll`.

Comment: This worked! Much appreciated. I was linking the source script in the head (as I always have), and for some reason placing it at the bottom worked.

Answer (score 0):

Placed the  at the bottom of the document within the  tags, it started magically working. Thanks @aerial301

Answer (score -1):

I don't see a problem in your javascript code either.
Have you tried to wrap your code in the `document.onload(function)` event?
Example:

```
<script>
    document.onload(() => {
        // your javascript code here.
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Oxygen is spitting out an error when I attempt to place it within the HTML, I tried forcing it and the main domain spits out an error as well, it's not well formed. I also attempted to use &lt; in place of < (in order to fix the well-formedness error), and it still does not work